# Add an image to a header only on pages

Tags: wordpress, image, header

I'm using wordpress and I would like to add an image to a header only on pages (Not posts).

Do you have a function for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the Theme by yourself? If yes, you can use this function right where you want to show the image:

```
<?php if(is_page()){
    // The image
} ?>
```

If not you could create a child Theme. If you find `page.php` inside your Theme folder, copy this file into your child theme folder. If not, search for `singular.php` or if this does not exist either `index.php`. Copy one of them into your child theme folder and put the image there using the code above `if(is_page()){`.

Answer (score 0):

In your theme->header.php,Look for this block of code. It has 4 lines(approx).

```
<?php $header_image = get_header_image();

 ( There are 2 lines in this area, just don't touch them )

<?php endif; ?>
```

When found, add our code to the top line and the bottom line like this

```
<?php if( is_page() ) : ?>
<?php $header_image = get_header_image();

 ( There are 2 lines in this area, just don't touch them )

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Remember, you are editing a php file live, so you must be very careful and it should go without saying that you should already have a backup, and FTP login just in case if something goes wrong.

```
// When any single Page is being displayed.

<?php if( is_page() ) : ?>
        <?php $header_image = get_header_image();
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: But i'm not sure if I explained my self good. I would like to have a code to put in my function.php file to add an image to the header just bellow the menu. like if page is page, add image "image.jpg". do you have something like that? Thanks a lot